# Clear Thunderbird junk folder or leave the messages in?

Tags: thunderbird, spam-prevention

Do the mails in the Thunderbird Junk folder serve any purpose, e.g. training data for the adaptive filters? Or can I throw them away?

Related but not containing my answer: [How does Thunderbird "decide" what is junk?](https://superuser.com/questions/1090296/how-does-thunderbird-decide-what-is-junk)

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the source code for the bayesian filter, the header file `nsBayesianFilter.h` implies that there is a training data file:

https://github.com/mozilla/releases-comm-central/blob/master/mailnews/extensions/bayesian-spam-filter/nsBayesianFilter.h#L162

```
/**
 * Implements storage of a collection of message tokens and counts for
 * a corpus of classified messages
 */

class CorpusStore : public TokenHash {
 public:
  CorpusStore();
  ~CorpusStore();
```

and

```
  /**
   * write the corpus information to file storage
   *
   * @param aMaximumTokenCount  prune tokens if number of tokens exceeds
   *                            this value.  == 0  for no pruning
   */
  void writeTrainingData(uint32_t aMaximumTokenCount);
```

And the implementation, in `nsBayesianFilter.cpp`, mentions a `training.dat` file:

https://github.com/mozilla/releases-comm-central/blob/master/mailnews/extensions/bayesian-spam-filter/nsBayesianFilter.cpp#L2251

```
nsresult CorpusStore::getTrainingFile(nsIFile** aTrainingFile) {
  // should we cache the profile manager's directory?
  nsCOMPtr<nsIFile> profileDir;

  nsresult rv = NS_GetSpecialDirectory(NS_APP_USER_PROFILE_50_DIR,
                                       getter_AddRefs(profileDir));
  NS_ENSURE_SUCCESS(rv, rv);
  rv = profileDir->Append(u"training.dat"_ns);
  NS_ENSURE_SUCCESS(rv, rv);

  return profileDir->QueryInterface(NS_GET_IID(nsIFile), (void**)aTrainingFile);
}
```

I'm not a Thunderbird developer, but my gut tells me that it would be safe to delete the junk mail itself, as the insights derived from it are stored in this `training.dat` file.